# System.InvalidOperationException: IDX202803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-6.0

I have deployed my .NET Core 6 Web API in IIS and in the identity column I have configured admin account but I am facing the IO exception intermittently when we hit the API. Please find the logs below.

> Exception occurred while processing message.
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync() Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'System.String'. at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()**

In the startup.cs I have this. Don't know what could be the problem or If I am missing any configuration in the IIS when identity provided

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Authorization:Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Authorization:Jwt:Audience"],
            };
            options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authorization:Jwt:MetaAddress"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; } };
        });
```

Tried adding authority in the startup.cs config:

```
options.Authority = Configuration["Authorization:Jwt:Issuer"];
```

and in the IIS app pool config set LoadUserProfile to true, but nothing works

[IIS load user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qdtr.png)

Comment: 1) Do not post code as images, code is text 2) It seems that you need to fix your config.

Comment: Does your project work fine locally? The problem seems to be with your code.

Comment: @samwu Project is working fine. this issue occurring intermittently

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, you can try to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.